# How do I tell rebar3 to use werl on Windows?

Tags: erlang, rebar

This may apply to any rebar commands but it is mostly about `rebar shell`.

By default rebar uses `erl` and this might be clunky on Windows shells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this source](https://github.com/erlang/rebar3/issues/1881#issuecomment-465451947)

> You can run rebar3 (and any other escript) with `werl` by specifying the
> `ESCRIPT_EMULATOR` environment variable. In a Git bash that would be:
>
> ```
> ESCRIPT_EMULATOR=werl rebar3 shell
> ```

Comment: Good, on windows I simply create the environment variable using control panel -> system -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables. and that's it.